# Function definition and function call produce syntax error in python 3, even when copied and pasted

Tags: python, syntax

I am trying to solve the problem of a least squares fit of a power law spliced to a third order polynomial in python using gradient descent. I have computed gradients with respect to the parameters in Matlab. The boundary conditions I computed by hand. I am running into a syntax error in my chi-squared minimization algorithm, which must take into account the boundary conditions. I am doing this for a machine learning class in which I am completing a somewhat self-directed and self-proposed long term project, but I am stuck because of this syntax error that I am not sure how to overcome. I will not get class credit for this. It is simply something to put on my resume.

```
def polypowerderiv(x,a1,b1,c1,a2,b2,c2,d2,boundaryx,ydat):


    #need to minimize square of ydat-polypower
    #from Mathematica, to be careful
    gradd2=2*(d2+c2*x+b2*x**2+a2*x**3-ydat)
    gradc2=gradd2*x
    gradb2=gradc2*x
    grada2=gradb2*x

    #again from Mathematica, to be careful
    gradc1=2(c+a1*x**b1-ydat)
    grada1=gradc1*x**b1
    gradb1=grada1*a1*log(x)

    return [np.sum(grada1),np.sum(gradb1),\
        np.sum(gradc1),np.sum(grada2),np.sum(gradb2),\
        np.sum(gradc2),np.sum(gradd2)]


def manualleastabsolutedifference(xdat, ydat, params,seed, maxiter, learningrate):
    chisq=0 #chisq is the L2 error of the fit relative to the ydata
    dof=len(xdat)-len(params)
    xparams=seed
    for step in np.arange(maxiter):
        a1,b1,c1,a2,b2,c2,d2=params
        chisq=polypowerlaw(xdat,params)
        for i in np.arange(len(xdat)):
            grad=np.zeros(len(seed))
            for i in np.arange(seed):


        polypowerlawboundarysolver=\
        polypowerboundaryconstraint(xdat,a1,b1,c1,a2,b2,c2)

        boundaryx=minimize(polypowerlawboundarysolver,x0=1000) 
        #hard coded to be half of len(xdat)
        chisq+=abs(ydat-\ 
            polypower(xdat,a1,b1,c1,a2,b2,c2,d2,boundaryx)
        grad=\
            polypowerderiv(xdat,a1,b1,c1,\
            a2,b2,c2,d2,boundaryx,ydat)

    params+=learningrate*grad
return params
```

The error I get is:

 File "", line 14
    grad=polypowerderiv(xdat,a1,b1,c1,a2,b2,c2,d2,boundaryx,ydat)
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Also, I'm having some small trouble with formatting. Please help. This one of my first few posts to Stack Overflow ever, after many years of up and down votes. Thank you for your extensive help, community.

Comment: Count your parentheses in `chisq+=abs(ydat-polypower(xdat,a1,b1,c1,a2,b2,c2,d2,boundaryx)`.

Comment: Found some rather significant additional bugs. In converting from the L1 to L2 error I dropped some squares and sums. The derivatives correspond to the L2 error. L1 error is nice for if statements if the boundary conditions don't match, was my theory. Anyhow, this code is a mess.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per Alan-Fey, you forgot a closing bracket:

```
chisq+=abs(ydat-\ 
            polypower(xdat,a1,b1,c1,a2,b2,c2,d2,boundaryx)
```

should be

```
chisq+=abs(ydat-\ 
            polypower(xdat,a1,b1,c1,a2,b2,c2,d2,boundaryx))
```

Comment: There is a close reason for typos. Why have you decided to answer instead?

Comment: BTW, you could remove the backslash.

Comment: It's Aran, not Alan.

Comment: Thank you. I actually didn't know that the Jupyter interpreter (I'm usually a command line programmer) would identify a wrong line as the source of a problem regularly like that. I'm still struggling with this one. This really solved it for me. I hope I can figure it out next time.

Comment: @StevenJD a missing closing bracket is invalid syntax regardless of your interpreter

Comment: I agree, but in C++ and in compiled python at the command line, it usually tells you which line is actually the problem.

Comment: I thought it was a bug in python. The line identified had no bug in it. Please feel free to close it now that you have demonstrated me wrong.

Comment: @StevenJD quoting your error: "*File "", line 14*". +-1 line precision. Of course the +-1 can be surprising the first time you see it.

Comment: True. But if you see that in C++, it will usually give you an error that clearly indicates that a parentheses or bracket is the problem, even if it gets the line wrong. I'm a relatively new python programmer, with more experience in C++, C, Matlab, and Fortran, and while I may have relatively advanced numerical skills, the error messages are still a mystery to me. Thank you.